# The output is differ when debugging vs Step Into solution

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a very strange problem that I never been in touch with in my entire life.

**This is what I been up to:** 
I have programmed a game that involves you going to throw two dices and the sum of the two dices should be seven for you to win.

**This is how the interface is built:**

- The textbox1 shows the value of first thrown dice.
- The textbox2 shows the value of second thrown dice.
- The textbox3 shows the sum of the both dices.
- The button1 throws the dices.

**This is the problem:**

- When i Debugg (F5) the application in *Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate*
  the textboxes gets the exactly same value all the time. This is wrong, it shouldn't act like this.
- When i Step Into (F11) the application/code the textboxes gets
  different values, just as it should be, this is right, this is how the program should act.

Is there anyone that can help with this problem, i think that I have just missed a very small but a obvious thing that I have missed but I really can't find anything, I'm actually out of ideas!

### Attachments

Here is all the files, I hope it will help you, the program is written in Swedish but I don't think that makes any problem, if it do, I can translate the whole solution to English.

**The whole Solution:** [Throw_Dices.zip](http://xave.se/Throw_Dices.zip)

**The Code**: [Big picture on three screens of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkUpf.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you change the Random line to Random rad = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)?

Comment: @MikeCheel: That's unlikely to be the problem. The default Random constructor seeds off the current time anyway.

Comment: @MikeCheel When I put DateTime.Now.Millisecond in it the exactly same problems remain.

Comment: He could however be on the right track with the time issue. Have you tried only using on single, static instance of Random? If you create multiple instances very close to each other, they all might have the same seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h343ddh9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> different Random objects that are created in close succession by a
>   call to the default constructor will have identical default seed
>   values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers

In your `Kasta.cs`, create a static instance of Random instead of multiple ones.

```
public class Tarning
{
    private static Random ran = new Random();
    int slump;
    public int Kasta()
    {
        //Random ran = new Random();
        slump = ran.Next(1, 6);
        return slump;
    }
}
```

Another possibility would be to create a seed manually. For instance like

```
public int Kasta()
{
    byte[] seed = new byte[4];
    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(seed);
    int seedInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(seed, 0);
    Random ran = new Random(seedInt);
    slump = ran.Next(1, 6);
    return slump;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two Dice (Tarning ?)

Create one and roll it twice.

Or create both on start up, Or perhaps have a class that holds 2 dice.
and throw them again.

You should also google random and seeding, what's happening is from the same seed value, you get the same sequence of random numbers. Debugging is introducing enough of a delay between the new Random calls, that the seed (based on the clock) has changed between the two calls.

PS your button1Click handler

should set the three textbox values, not trigger textbox changed events which then set them. Imagine if you wanted to reuse your code, you'd have to create a UI to do it.

A better way would be to have a class that held two (or n) dice with a Roll method and a property that returned the result. Then you could reuse it without worrying about when and how.

Comment: I new that there was a to easy to be good! Do you have a little example on how I can change the VALUE instead of trigger the event? This is the first time I am using Windows Forms, I have been programming C# in console for over a year now but so it's kind of confusing for me to learn the Windows Forms Logic.